# is there a shorter way to implement multi-replacements in a single String

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I have a string that may contains the next characters '&' and/or '<' and/or '>'

for each one of these characters I need to replace it with Charater ref in html :

- '&' ->  "&amp ;"
- '<' ->  '&lt ;'
- '>' ->  '&gt ;'

I have implimented this using the following code and it's working:

```
if( _.contains(note,"&")){
    note = note.replace("&","&amp;");
}if( _.contains(note,"<")){
    note = note.replace("<","&lt;");
}if( _.contains(note,">")){
    note = note.replace(">","&gt;");
                }
return note;
```

is there a shorter way to impliment this ?

Comment: You could also skip the "if"s

Comment: used _.escape() since I have underscore already set up in my project